# Using Custom ActionBar in ListActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-listfragment, listactivity

HI friends I'm newbie in android and need Your help very much.
I have an Activity extended ListActivity I want to add Custom ActionBar to it.
Some friends suggested to use ListFragment but i couldn't do it.
To using custom ActionBar in other activities like MainActivity I extended it from custom ActionBar activity and called actionbar method.

Tank You All.

**ListActivity:**

```
public class AlbumsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector                 cd;

    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager                 alert           = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog             pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser                         jsonParser      = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList;

    // albums JSONArray
    JSONArray                          albums          = null;

    // albums JSON url
    private static final String        URL_ALBUMS      = "http://api.androidhive.info/songs/albums.php";

    // ALL JSON node names
    private static final String        TAG_ID          = "id";
    private static final String        TAG_NAME        = "name";
    private static final String        TAG_SONGS_COUNT = "songs_count";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_albums);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check for internet connection
        if ( !cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(AlbumsActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        // Hashmap for ListView
        albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading Albums JSON in Background Thread
        new LoadAlbums().execute();

        // get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        /**
         * Listview item click listener
         * TrackListActivity will be lauched by passing album id
         * */
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {
                // on selecting a single album
                // TrackListActivity will be launched to show tracks inside the album
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackListActivity.class);

                // send album id to tracklist activity to get list of songs under that album
                String album_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_id)).getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("album_id", album_id);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all Albums by making http request
     * */
    class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AlbumsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Listing Albums ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        /**
         * getting Albums JSON
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

            try {
                albums = new JSONArray(json);

                if (albums != null) {
                    // looping through All albums
                    for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item values in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_SONGS_COUNT);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_SONGS_COUNT, songs_count);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        albumsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
                }

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList,
                            R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[]{ TAG_ID,
                                    TAG_NAME, TAG_SONGS_COUNT }, new int[]{
                                    R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name, R.id.songs_count });

                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

**CustomActionBar:**

```
public class CustomActionBar extends Activity {

    public void actionbarMethod() {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View actionBarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams
                (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ImageView btnmenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnmenu);

        btnmenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);

                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends CustomActionBar {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            actionbarMethod();
    ..................
    }
 }
```

Comment: i would  use a layout with height of 48dp at the top of every layout. on which you can set primary color and click events.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout with a custom `Toolbar` (which is the newer version of `ActionBar` specifically made to allow customizations) and then include that layout in the layout for any activity you want to use it in.